# Background thread causes application crash without error after rotate

Tags: xamarin.android

I have a set of long database operations that I run in a BackgroundWorker in order to keep the UI responsive.

If the device is rotated while this background thread is still running, the normal Activity lifecycle runs (OnPause() etc...) and the View is reloaded as I would expect. Shortly after the view has reloaded, the whole application crashes without any related error message or debug output in ddms as far as I can tell.

The crash doesn't seem to be the result of an Exception. Within the background thread I wrap the database operations in try/catches and they are never triggered. What kinds of errors should I be looking for that would not trigger an exception?

Comment: If you are passing the Context (Activity, View or anything that derives from Android.App.Context) to the thread, the thread may be trying to access a disposed object.

Comment: Thanks, Matthew. I am passing a delegate which was a member variable of the View. Interestingly, the delegate still gets called when the database routine finishes and the view state is "gone". I'm still not sure what caused the crash and why I don't get any error output, but I've found I can prevent it with the observer pattern. I register the view as an observer for the database operation in OnResume and unregister it in OnPause.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you put some UI related work in BackgroudWorker. Run these methods by using `RunOnUiThread()`.